# p5.js: Uncaught TypeError: dialog.createElement is not a function

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!
Пилил я значит веб-страничку простенькую с использованием `p5.js`...
Нужно было сделать так, чтобы по клику на иконку создавался `HTML`-элемент `<p>`.

```js
let msg;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  // creating message boxes 
  dialog = select("#dialog");
  dialog.createElement('p', 'hello!!!');
}

function putMsg(msg) {
  setup();
}
```

```html
<div id="mike" onclick="putMsg(msg)">
  <img src="images/mike.ico" alt="microphone">
</div>
<div id="dialog" class="scroll">
</div>
```

И `dialog.createElement` вызывает ошибку:

```
createElement is not a  function
```

`p5` подключил как надо, что делать с этим - не знаю... Подскажите пожалуйста :))

Comment: https://discourse.processing.org/t/p5-dom-js-createelement-function-not-able-to-set-properties/4196 не?

Answer (score 0):

```
let dialog = select("#dialog");
```

Переменная не объявлена. А присваиваете так, как будто уже объявлена. У вас просто

```
dialog = select("#dialog");
```

Comment: Не-а. Объявил переменную и всё та же ошибка.